# put two html element in same line with custom css

Tags: css

there is two html element inside of a

li element and I need to put these two in same line,

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<li class="linkedin">
       <i class="fa fa-linkedin"></i>
       <a href="#" target="_blank">https://www.linkedin.com/in/mehmet-yener-yilmaz-
           833a07101/</a>
    </li>
```

sive, I need some css tricks to handle it efficiently

edited: i tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9067892/how-to-align-two-elements-on-the-same-line-without-changing-html) and some others like it but cant resolve my issue

Comment: Why don't you `float` the fontawesome icon `left`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `word-break:break-all` to break word if they are single line without any space. and `flex` to get proper inline text with used icons.

Just add following css

```
    .sidebar-wrapper .contact-list li {
        margin-bottom: 15px;
        word-break: break-all; /* Added */
        display:flex;   /* Added */
    }
```

Comment: I will accept this answer but can you tell me whats diffirence "display: flex" and "word-break". when I should use this display:flex stuff?

Comment: I added explanation  please check. flex can use when you need in single line. more info  https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Answer (score 1):

just add **display : flex** to the css of li to

```
.sidebar-wrapper .contact-list li {
    margin-bottom: 15px;
    display: flex;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is the solution. It will provide you ellipsis for long text & for entire **linkedin url** keep a **tooltip**.

```css
.linkedin { 
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
}

.linkedin > a {
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I will keep this also!